# Hopf Bifurcation Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, bifurcation, limit-cycles

I have a 2D dynamical system of the form

\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=f(x,y,K) \\[1ex]
\dot{y}=g(x,y,K)
\end{cases}

where $K$ is a free parameter (later I can write the system here). I've found two Hopf bifurcations at approximately $K=0.69$ and $K=0.84$. In between these two values, there is a clear stable limit cycle, and for $K<0.69$ and $K>0.84$ the oscilations die after some time $t$.

Furthermore, after computing the eigenvalues, I can see that the real part of the eigenvalue is negative for $K<0.69$ and $K>0.84$, and it is positive for $0.69<K<0.81$.

With all this, I think I can say that **there is a supercritical bifurcation at $K=0.69$ because there are stable oscillations for $K>0.69$. As for $K=0.84$**, I don't think we can say anything unless we go to Hopf theorem in [here](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucesgvd/hopf.pdf), and compute the derivative of the real part of the eigenvalue and the $a$ value which I think is the 1st Lyapunov coefficient (although I have no idea how the complicated expression for this coefficient turns out to be equal to this...?)

Now, the problem is that I've computed these two things at $K=0.69$ and $K=0.84$ and they are both positive in the two cases. So, according to the theorem this would mean that periodic solutions exist for $K<0.69$ and $K<0.84$. The second case is correct, but the first is not.

Moreover, the theorem states that the fixed point is stable for $K<0.69$ and $K<0.84$, and unstable for $K>0.84$, which is clearly not the case as it is easy to see from the signal of the real part of the eigenvalues!

So, what's happening here?

EDIT: The system is:

\begin{cases}
\dot{x}=-\frac{8}{3}(-0.99e^{-0.01y}+1)(x^2-x)+Kxy\\[1ex]
\dot{y}=\frac{4}{x^{3/2}}\left(-y+1+\frac{3}{2}\frac{y}{x}(x-1)-0.1\frac{x-1}{y+1}-K\right)
\end{cases}

and the nullclines+vector field for the case $K=0.69$ is:

[image]

EDIT2: After discussing in the comments with [Evgeny](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/87697/evgeny), I realized that I was evaluating the derivative of the real part of the egeinvalue incorrectly. Indeed, by simply analysing that it changes from negative to positive at $K=0.69$ and from positive to negative at $K=0.84$, we can say that its derivative at these points is positive and negative, respectively.

Furthermore, because the first Lyapunov coefficient is positive in both cases, we can conclude through Hopf theorem that there is a subcritical bifurcation at $K=0.69$ and a supercritical at $K=0.84$. So this means that the stable periodic oscillations that I mentioned I can clearly see between $K=0.69$ and $K=0.84$ are due to the supercritical bifucartion at $K=0.84$, and not the bifurcation at $K=0.69$.

EDIT3: I've just realized that the conclusions I've drawn in EDIT2 are not consistent with Hopf theorem! And so my question still remains:

The real part of the eigenvalue is positive for $0.69<K<0.84$ and negative for $K<0.69$ and for $K>0.84$. For $K<0.69$ I get this situation:

[image]

which I can't understand if it's a no limit-cycle situation or an unstable situation. For $0.69<K<0.84$ I have this situation:

[image]

which is clearly a stable limit cycle! Finally for $K>0.84$ I get a situation similar to $K<0.69$. With all this, it seems that the first Lyapunoc coefficient should be negative! But when I do the calculation I get a positive one!

Comment: Just few comments: 1) If you've already found equilibrium curves for your system, would you mind sharing it with others to ease answering the question? It's not easy looking nonlinear equation to solve, at first glance at least. 2) PDF from your link has some missing notation, especially concerning where w.r.t. critical value of parameter limit cycle exists. Can you check your calculations against [Scholarpedia](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation#Two-dimensional_Case)?

Comment: @Evgeny I've just added the nullclines+vector field. As for the Scholarpedia, there are two important values: the derivative of the real part of the eigenvalue and 1st coefficient of Lyapunov, just like in the pdf I've posted. The thing is that I'm not sure how the Lyapunov coefficient is equal to that expression in terms of third and second derivatives of $f$ and $g$ (I don't know how to evaluate it in the way Scholarpedia writes it).

Comment: 2) Just use the last formula in [this section](http://www.scholarpedia.org/article/Andronov-Hopf_bifurcation#First_Lyapunov_Coefficient). You can compute derivatives of RHS symbolically and just plug equilibria coordinates. 1) I mean, everyone who would want to analyze bifurcations here would like to know equilibria coordinates depending on $K$. Have you solved the equation for them or have coordinates only numerically?

Comment: The last formula in that section is the same as the one on the pdf I've provided. And it is positive in the both cases I've provided in my question. I only have numerical solutions. I don't think we could get analytical solutions for this specific system...

Comment: The $d$ quantity can't be positive at both values of parameters. If you increase parameter value and equilibrium goes from stable to unstable, then $d > 0$, but going from unstable to stable implies that $d < 0$. There must be some error in your calculations at least when you are computing $d$.

Comment: If the equilibrium points $x_0,y_0$ were always the same (don't depend on $K$), then that would make sense to me; indeed, it would almost result from the partial derivative definition! But the equilibrium positions change with $K$, so that still applies?

Comment: Ah, I think I got it. It's a total derivative, not partial. So $d=\frac{\partial a}{\partial K}+\frac{\partial a}{\partial x_0}\frac{\partial x_0}{\partial K}+\frac{\partial a}{\partial y_0}\frac{\partial y_0}{\partial K}$, with $a$ the real part of the eigenvalue. Correct? In this case, numerically I can't get the value of $d$ because I'm solving numerically a system with three equations that gives me $x_0$, $y_0$ and $K$.

Comment: So, by just analysing the signal of the real part of the eigenvalue I can conclude in this case that both of the bifurcations are supercritical, right?
If that's OK, now there is just one thing of the theorem that it's bothering me which is the one that states "a unique curve of periodic solutions bifurcates from the fixed point into the region $\mu>\mu_0$ if $ad<0$ or $\mu<\mu_0$ if $ad>0$. In this case it's the oposite... So where's the snag?

Comment: You can't say what exactly happens by analyzing only real part of eigenvalues. Even if you increase parameter value and real part of eigenvalues changes from negative to positive through zero at critical point, there are still two options how stability is lost: a) unstable limit cycle exists before critical point, collides with equilibrium and makes it unstable, no limit cycle in vicinity after the critical value of parameter; b) equilibrium is stable before the critical point, but limit cycle takes away stability after the critical point. These cases are distinguished by first Lyapunov value.

Comment: To compute sign of $d$ you just use the direction in which real part of eigenvalues of equilibrium change when you increase $K$. It doesn't depend on the fact if equilibrium is changed by changing $K$ or not. If you have the same sign of Lyapunov value at both critical points, you must have different types of Andronov-Hopf bifurcation since $d$ has different signs at different critical values. That's how this theorem works: you have to know both quantities to tell what limit cycle (stable, unstable) exists and where w.r.t. critical point (before or after).

Comment: @Evgeny thanks for your help! I've made a second EDIT in my question with all the conclusions. Take a look and feel free to post an answer.

Comment: I almost agree with your conclusions except for description of changes in phase portrait. For me the description is the following. A stable focus loses stability at $K \approx 0.69$, becomes an unstable focus and spawns a stable limit cycle. This limit cycle exists when $0.69 < K < 0.84$, but at $K \approx 0.84$ it stucks back to the equilibrium, ceases to exist and unstable focus becomes stable again. I can't memorize which one is subcritical and which is supercritical, but this seems to be consistent with eigenvalue derivatives and Lyapunov values.

Comment: The true picture however depends on what happened with limit cycle when $0.69 < K < 0.84$, but essentially that changes not a lot if we are talking only about this equilibrium and its Hopf bifurcations.

Comment: @Evgeny I've just realized that the conclusions are not consistent with the fact that the first lyapunov coefficient is positive in both cases! In EDIT3 I've written my question in a more clear way.

Comment: I don't get what is the inconsistency here. When $K < 0.69$ you always had a stable focus: the first picture in EDIT3 is what stable focus usually looks like. There is no limit cycle, the focus is stable, and trajectory goes to it.

Comment: As a sanity check, study numerically two things. 1) After focus loses stability, what is the amplitude of attracting limit cycle? Is it close to an equilibrium and grows with changing $K$, or is it comparably big right after the bifurcation? 2) Pick a point near the stable focus for $K < 0.69$ and integrate your system backwards in time. Does trajectory go to a limit cycle? If the answer to both questions is "no", there is something wrong with your calculation of a first Lyapunov value. If the answer is "yes", that would be interesting.

Comment: @Evgeny the inconstency is that if the derivative of the real part of the EV is positive and the Lyapunov coeff. is also positive (we have both conditions at $K=0.69$), then according to the theorem we should go from an unstable LC situation to a no-LC situation as $K$ crosses $0.69$.

Comment: 1) Right after $K=0.69$ the oscillations' amplitude grows with increasing $K$: at $0.69$ the amplitude is roughly 2.2, at $0.70$ is 3.8 and at $0.71$ is 5.0

Comment: If your observations and calculations are correct, I think the bifurcation scenario is the following. When $K < 0.69$ there are two attractors in this system: stable focus and stable limit cycle (check that numerically!). These two attractors are separated by an unstable limit cycle. At $K \approx 0.69$ unstable limit cycle collides with a stable focus, and right after that you see big-amplitude stable limit cycle (if your observation about amplitude rougly 2.2 is correct). At $K \approx 0.84$ this limit cycle collides with unstable focus and focus becomes stable again.

Comment: Note that statement of Andronov-Hopf bifurcations should be interpreted correctly. Everything is considered in some appropriate small neighbourhood of an equilibrium points. The conclusion refers only to small-amplitude oscillations. So there is no inconsistency in that you can see large-amplitude oscillations for a parameters that are told to have no small-amplitude oscillations.

Comment: Indeed, for $K<0.69$ there are two fixed points, but it is a focus (that gives birth to the LC) and a saddle, which doesn't disappear after $K=0.69$...

Comment: Hum, so what you suggest in your last comment is that we are probably out of the conditions of the theorem?

Comment: 1) I'm talking about attractors. Saddle is not an attractor. When you have $K > 0.69$ pick a point near the stable limit cycle. Memorize that point and check if you go to the limit cycle from this point (or its vicinity) when $K < 0.69$. 2) I'm suggesting that if you see unstable small-amplitude cycle before critical value and large-amplitude stable limit cycle after the critical value, it doesn't contradict theorem about Andronov-Hopf bifurcation. It's perfectly compatible with that since theorem deals with small parameter values and small neighbourhood of focus.